# How do I post two uneven arrays where one set is checkboxes and the other text input boxes

Tags: php, mysql, post

I can't get this to work. I need to update many records in 1 column, based on what's checked and filled out. I tried different combinations of checking and unchecking and having the text fields blank or not blank, and in this php post code i tried many different things, but can't figure out the correct combinations and if/elses or issets or empties, etc.

the values in the checkboxes correspond to record/row IDs. all the text boxes will be prefilled with prices. all the checkboxes will be dynamically checked or unchecked. a person can undo checked checkboxes if they want or check checkboxes that are not checked. on post, all the records that are checked should get the matching text box value.

the problem is i can't get the 2 arrays to match in my post. for example, in this sample set of fields, let's say i check the 2nd checkbox and the 4th checkbox. the records that should update and the values that should save into the column should be as follows...

```
2 -> 17.67
4 -> 19.84
```

but instead i get:

```
2 -> 16.95
4 -> 17.67
```

or this (if i remove the values from 1st and 3rd text boxes):

```
2 -> empty
4 -> 17.67
```

or this (2nd checkbox id and value missing completely)

```
4 -> 17.67
```

what am i doing wrong?

```
if (isset($_POST["savelist"]) && !empty($_POST["savelist"])) {
    $productidcheckboxes = isset($_POST['productid']) ? $_POST['productid'] : array();
    $listprices = isset($_POST['listprice']) ? $_POST['listprice'] : array();
    //other things i tried
    //$listprices = (empty($_POST['listprice'])) ? $_POST['listprice'] : array();
    //$listprices = (!empty($_POST['listprice'])) ? $_POST['listprice'] : array();
    //$productidcheckboxes = $_POST['productid'];
    //$listprices = $_POST['listprice'];
    $new = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<count($productidcheckboxes); $i++) {
        $new[] = $productidcheckboxes[$i];
        $new[] = $listprices[$i];
    }
    $k=0;
    foreach ($new as $value) {
        $k++;
        if($k==1){
            $theid = $value;
        }
        if($k==2){
            $thelistprice = $value;
            //different ifs i tried
            //if ($theid<>"")
            //if ($value<>"")
            //if ($theid<>"" && $thelistprice<>"")
            //if ($theid<>"" && $value<>"")
            if ($thelistprice<>"")
            {
                echo $theid.": ";
                echo $thelistprice."<br>";
                //update table with the list prices
                //mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET mylistprices = '$thelistprice' WHERE id = $theid");
            }
            $theid = "";
            $thelistprice = "";
            $k=0;
        }
    }
}
```

form looks like this

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="productid[]">
<input type="text" value="16.95" name="listprice[]">

<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="productid[]">
<input type="text" value="17.67" name="listprice[]">

<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="productid[]">
<input type="text" value="18.81" name="listprice[]">

<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="productid[]">
<input type="text" value="19.84" name="listprice[]">

<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="productid[]">
<input type="text" value="16.85" name="listprice[]">

<input type="submit" value="Save List" name="savelist">

</form>
```

by the way, by uneven i mean all the checkboxes will have values so correct rows will be updated, but the text boxes may or may not be filled. i would like it if i didn't have to clear any values in checkboxes or text inputs. it should just update records that are checked with it's corresponding values, and ignore non-checked checkboxes and the non-checked checkboxes corresponding values. but in the end, i may have to change how it's done, but i can't solve this one.

Comment: Can you do `<input type="checkbox" value="16.95" name="item[1]"><input type="text" value="16.95" />`?

Comment: not sure. doesn't text box need a name too?

Comment: No, because the value is passed in the checkbox. The downside is the value can't be update. I presume since it's a text input, it should be editable?

Comment: yes it's going to be editable. so on first visit values not saved to db yet. want to save to db, but i can't get that far. then on next visit if record has price, it shows the db value. a person can change it and resave. but i can't even work on resave until i solve first save.

Comment: Then on this page, do a hardcoded numeric in the names `productid[1]`and `listprice[1]`counting up. Then all the keys will match.

Comment: no clue how to implement what you're talking about.

Comment: Well you have all these inputs that have `productid[]` and `listprice[]` as the names. Instead do `<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="productid[1]">
<input type="text" value="16.85" name="listprice[1]">`. You turn random arrays in to specific matched keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add hardcoded numeric values to the form names so they match up in your processing page. Right now they are random:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="productid[1]">
    <input type="text" value="16.95" name="listprice[1]">

    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="productid[2]">
    <input type="text" value="17.67" name="listprice[2]">

    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="productid[3]">
    <input type="text" value="18.81" name="listprice[3]">

    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="productid[4]">
    <input type="text" value="19.84" name="listprice[4]">

    <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="productid[5]">
    <input type="text" value="16.85" name="listprice[5]">
    <input type="submit" value="Save List" name="savelist">
</form>
```

Now you know if the user checks `product[4]`, it really is `product[4]`. When you leave your keys blank like `productid[]`, that is just an anonymous spot in the array and makes it impossible to track when dealing with checkboxes that have no value unless checked.

If you check off `productid[2]` and `productid[4]` you know that the values in the `listprice` array are the values that go with what you have checked off:

```
Array
(
    [listprice] => Array
        (
            [1] => 16.95
            [2] => 17.67
            [3] => 18.81
            [4] => 19.84
            [5] => 16.85
        )

    [productid] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
            [4] => 4
        )
```

)

To access the values, loop through the `productid` but access the `listprice`:

```
foreach($_POST['productid'] as $key => $value){
    echo $_POST['listprice'][$value].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: another alternative group naming would be `product[1][id]` and `product[1][price]`, in row format

Comment: @Ghost Yeah that will work too. Probably cleaner array that way.

Comment: ok about the html part, but how does php part go to grab the sets and keys?

Comment: if i do this, it just takes from one set. how do i merge in second set? foreach($_POST['productid'] as $key=>$value){echo "$key=$value<br>";}

Comment: You can do a couple things. Give me a second, it's just a loop

Comment: if i do this, it makes correct id and price match, but it uses every field instead of just the checked ones: foreach($_POST['listprice'] as $key=>$value){echo "$key=$value<br>";}

Comment: In that instance you do echo $_POST['listprice'][$value];

Comment: thanks, that worked: foreach($_POST['productid'] as $key=>$value){echo $key."=".$_POST['listprice'][$value]."<br>";}

Comment: I just edited the answer, but sounds like you got it!